# Flutter imagepicker menu bar background color on android

Tags: image, flutter, picker

I wanted to use the image_picker plugin from https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker .

However how can I change the background color of the menu bar ?

In my main.dart file,

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Gigforce",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          ),
```

But when the imagepicker is displayed on android, the menu bar background is dark blue.

I've searched everywhere but can't find any solution to it.

The menu bar of the image picker should be consistent with the remaining pages.

Comment: Hi, Did you found any solution for this ? I'm also facing this issue.

Comment: Any updates or better plugins ... ?